# jquery click events not working in mobile (click touchstart) on dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic chatbot I created and need the user to be able to interact with the app via button pushes. On each 'turn' (when a user responds) I append controls that look like these:

**Controls appended**

```
$("#controls").append(
                  '<button class="options one" value="certifications" id="certifications" type="button">My Certifications</button>' +
                  '<button class="options one" value="videos" id="video" type="button">My Videos</button>' +
                  '<button class="options one" value="login" id="login" type="button">My Account</button>'  
            );
```

From here, I have a function that takes the value/id of the clicked button and that picks what the bot reponds with, like so:

**Push user's value into chat window, respond with correlated value**

```
// Pushes user's selected values as text chats
$("#controls").on("click touchstart", ".options", function() {
    // Remove buttons on click
    $("#controls button.options").remove();
    var b_val = $(this).val();

    var newMsg = text;

    var prevState = $("#conversation").html();
    if (prevState.length > 3) {
        prevState = prevState;
    }
```

What could be causing this click not to work? I am using a delegated on click since it's a dynamic element, but that doesn't seem to fix anything.

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: check this post <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements">Event binding on dynamically created elements</a>

Comment: @Girish007, I'm using jquery 1.9, so I believe I'm following this binding rule: `$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});`